# Add a Process Indicator in a Word vba macro

Tags: vba, ms-word

I created a **Vba script in Word** for comparing several versions of same documents in a selected folder. The script allows to create new reports with results.

```
Private Sub SummaryReportButton_Click()
    Dim objDocA As Word.Document
    Dim objDocB As Word.Document
    Dim objDocC As Word.Document

    Dim objFSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim objFolderA As Scripting.Folder
    Dim objFolderB As Scripting.Folder
    Dim objFolderC As Scripting.Folder

    Dim colFilesA As Scripting.Files
    Dim objFileA As Scripting.File

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer

    Set objFSO = New FileSystemObject
    Set objFolderA = objFSO.GetFolder(ChooseFolder("Choose the folder with the original documents", ThisDocument.Path))
    Set objFolderB = objFSO.GetFolder(ChooseFolder("Choose the folder with revised documents", ThisDocument.Path))
    Set objFolderC = objFSO.GetFolder(ChooseFolder("Choose the folder for the comparisons documents", ThisDocument.Path))

    Set colFilesA = objFolderA.Files

    For Each objFileA In colFilesA
    If objFileA.Name Like "*.docx" Then
        Set objDocA = Documents.Open(objFolderA.Path & "\" & objFileA.Name)
        Set objDocB = Documents.Open(objFolderB.Path & "\" & objFileA.Name)
        Set objDocC = Application.CompareDocuments( _
            OriginalDocument:=objDocA, _
            RevisedDocument:=objDocB, _
            Destination:=wdCompareDestinationNew)
        objDocA.Close
        objDocB.Close
        On Error Resume Next
        Kill objFolderC.Path & "\" & objFileA.Name
        On Error GoTo 0
        objDocC.SaveAs FileName:=objFolderC.Path & "\" & objFileA.Name
        objDocC.Close SaveChanges:=False
    End If
    Next objFileA

End Sub

Function ChooseFolder(strTitle As String, strPath As String) As String
    Dim fldr As FileDialog
    Dim sItem As String


    Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With fldr
        .Title = strTitle
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = strPath
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With

NextCode:
    ChooseFolder = sItem
    Set fldr = Nothing
End Function
```

I would like to improve my script by displaying an indicator on the process until that it will be finished.

I thought to use a message box:

```
Msgbox  "Processing " & i & " of " &  colFilesA.Count
```

but that will need to be clicked each time... It's not the best solution...

Could you please help me to do a best solution ?

Thanks in advance for your help,

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `Application.StatusBar` for that. You could initialize and change text in status bar in this way:

```
Application.StatusBar = "Processing " & i & " of " &  colFilesA.Count
```

and at the end of your macro please add the following line to clean StatusBar message:

```
Application.Statusbar = false
```

Comment: The problem that The word results files are opened during a few time just before to be saved (with a pop-up "The document being saved contains track changes Continue with save?") and I don't know how to implement that for avoiding that

Comment: `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` would suppress any system alerts until you set the property back to `True`. While alerts are turned off Word will select the default response. You might test for the default by finding out which button in the alert box is pre-selected.

Comment: You can also insert `UserForm` with `.ShowModal` set to `False` that will be loaded when need and will show your progress in `Label`.